# Using Jquery Fancybox resize() function within an Iframe?

Tags: jquery, resize, fancybox

I am a beginner with Jquery and I am using Fancybox (type: iframe) within my PHP application.

Within the iframe, there is a form, once the user has filled & submitted the form, the Fancybox should resize so as to accomodate the data which will be relayed back once the formdata has been processed.

And I would also like the main page of the site to refresh once the user closes the Fancybox alert.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just had to deal with the same question, and I solved it by creating some helper functions for FancyBox. The **fb_resize(w,h)** function resizes the fancybox-content div then calls $.fancybox.resize() to adjust for the modified content. The **fb_close_any()** and **fb_resize_any(w,h)** functions can be called from within any content, including an iFrame, to close or resize the fancybox.

```
function fb_resize(w, h) {
  if (w > 0 || h > 0) {
    if (w > 0) $('#fancybox-content').css({ width: w+"px"});
    if (h > 0) $('#fancybox-content').css({ height: h+"px"});
    $.fancybox.resize();
  }
}

function fb_close_any() {
  window.top.eval('$.fancybox.close()');
}

function fb_resize_any(w, h) {
  w = (w > 0) ? w : 0;
  h = (h > 0) ? h : 0;
  window.top.eval('fb_resize('+w+','+h+')');
}
```